# jQuery .append Issue

Tags: jquery

This is my code:

```
$('.add').click(function(){
    $('#test').append("<div class='tab selected'>TEST</div>");
});
$('.tab').click(function(){
    $('.tab').removeClass('selected').addClass('unselected');
    $(this).removeClass('unselected').addClass('selected');
});

<input type='button' value='add' class='add' />
<div id='test'>
    <div class='tab unselected'>TEST</div>
</div>
```

This is my issue:

When I click the `.tab` div that was already defined in html, the function works fine.
But, if I add another `.tab` div using the `.add` input, the function does not work.

What exactly am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

The event handlers are bound to the element that exist at the time they are executed. In case of dynamic content updates, your bet is to either rebind the handler or use delegated events like below.

```
$('#test').on('click', '.tab', function(){
    $('.tab').removeClass('selected').addClass('unselected');
    $(this).removeClass('unselected').addClass('selected');
});
```

Or you can rebind like below,

```
$('.add').click(function(){
    $('.tab').removeClass('selected'); //comment from @MG_Bautista
    var newTab = $('<div />')
                   .addClass('tab selected')
                   .click(tabFx)
                   .text('Test');
    $('#test').append(newTab);
});

$('.tab').click(tabFx);

function tabFx(){
    $('.tab').removeClass('selected').addClass('unselected');
    $(this).removeClass('unselected').addClass('selected');
}
```

Comment: @Vega if you clic two or more times, the new tabs showed selected, the selection is unique, add `$('.tab').removeClass('selected')` before the line `$('.tab').append(newTab);`... @user1885099 read the comment...

Comment: @MG_Bautista Must be a bug from original code, fixed it though. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use either "live" or "on"...
if you are referencing jquery 1.7 or less then live will work....if you are using latest jquery use "on"

```
$('#test').on('click', '.tab', function(){
    $('.tab').removeClass('selected').addClass('unselected');
    $(this).removeClass('unselected').addClass('selected');
});
```

or

```
$('#test').live('click', '.tab', function(){
    $('.tab').removeClass('selected').addClass('unselected');
    $(this).removeClass('unselected').addClass('selected');
});
```

Comment: Even for older versions, `.delegate` is recommended over `.live`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this...

```
$('.add').click(function(){
    $('.tab').removeClass('selected').addClass('unselected');
    $('#test').append("<div class='tab selected'>TEST</div>");
});

$('#test').on('click', '.tab', function(){
    $('.tab').addClass('unselected');
    $(this).removeClass('unselected');
    $('.tab').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

And see [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Dbvf2/)